# Select image and display from textfield?

Tags: images, jquery

I use the built-in filemanager to select an image from a form.

```
    <input id="upload_image1" class="rp-input-field" type="text" name="f16" value="<?php echo isset($upload_image1);?>" readonly />
    <input class="upload_image_button" id="upload_image1" type="button" value="Upload image 1" />
```

The complete url is shown in the textbox and i'm fine with this. What I would like to achieve is to get the url from this text-field and dynamically display as image. If I change to another image, this image will be displayed instead. How can this be achieved? I assume some jQuery is involved or is there a better way achieving this?

Kind regards
Johan

Comment: What "built-in filemanager"? How is the data saved specifically? You have not provided enough information.

Comment: Judging from the code your provided you are using a full page reload to set `$upload_image1` so in theory you could simply use `<img src="<?php echo $upload_image1 ?>" />`. However, with the new Media Library it's not common to perform a page reload when selecting an image but rather hook into the "User selects image"-event. Please add more code so we can better understand your situation.

Comment: I have a form to add a new music record to a custom database. What I was showing above was the input field for adding a picture to this record. When clicking on "Upload image 1", the WordPress media window is opened on top of page where you can upload or select images from the library. When an image is selected it's complete url for the selected image is displayed in the input text field. What I would like to do is to automatically take the image URL from the input-field and maybe with jQuery display the selected image for the user. Does this clear things up a little bit more?